# Updating Total in Java Loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble updating the total for each time the loop runs.
I've been using the values 2, 50 and 5 to check my work.
The total should read: 3, 4.5, 6.75, 10.125, 15.1875, but all I can get is the first total.

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!!

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Population 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int startingOrganisms;
    int dailyPopulation;
    int daysMultiply;
    double dailyTotal = 0;
    double dailyTotal2 = 0;
    double dailyTotal3 = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Starting # of Organisms:");
    startingOrganisms = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Daily Population Increase(%):");
    dailyPopulation = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.println("# of Days They'll Multiply:");
    daysMultiply = keyboard.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i<=daysMultiply; i++)
    {
        dailyTotal = startingOrganisms*dailyPopulation*.01;
        dailyTotal2 = startingOrganisms + dailyTotal;
        System.out.println("Population for day " + i + " = " + dailyTotal2);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your logic, and the results it looks like you want to change `startingOrganisms` value as you loop through your for loop.

Given your input values as:`2, 50 and 5` and the result to be: `3, 4.5, 6.75, 10.125, 15.1875`, a *rough guess* would be `startingOrganisms` should be assigned the value of `dailyTotal2`

First change would to change the data type of `startingOrganisms`.

```
double startingOrganisms;
```

Next would be to change its value within the for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= daysMultiply; i++) {
            dailyTotal = startingOrganisms * dailyPopulation * .01;
            dailyTotal2 = startingOrganisms + dailyTotal;
            startingOrganisms = dailyTotal2;
            System.out.println("Population for day " + i + " = " + dailyTotal2);
        }
```

OR better, treat `startingOrganisms` as your `dailyTotal2` counter which holds the updated value and increments:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= daysMultiply; i++) {
            dailyTotal = startingOrganisms * dailyPopulation * .01;
            startingOrganisms = startingOrganisms + dailyTotal;
            //startingOrganisms = dailyTotal2
            System.out.println("Population for day " + i + " = " + startingOrganisms);
        }
```

The result in both the above cases you get here is what you expect:

```
Starting # of Organisms:
2
Daily Population Increase(%):
50
# of Days They'll Multiply:
5
Population for day 1 = 3.0
Population for day 2 = 4.5
Population for day 3 = 6.75
Population for day 4 = 10.125
Population for day 5 = 15.1875
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get only the first total cause you're calculating it only once!

You should read the input from the user and calculate in a loop:

```
while(daysMultiply != -1){ // when the user wants to quit he'll enter -1, for example
    daysMultiply = keyboard.nextInt();
    dailyTotal = 0;
    dailyTotal2 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<=daysMultiply; i++)
    {
        dailyTotal = startingOrganisms*dailyPopulation*.01;
        dailyTotal2 = startingOrganisms + dailyTotal;
        System.out.println("Population for day " + i + " = " + dailyTotal2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each day you are calculating based on the original population, not the current population.  Try adjusting the calculation to use the current population times the growth factor:

```
growth = dailyTotal*dailyPopulation*.01;
dailyTotal dailyTotal + growth;
```

or in one line

```
dailyTotal = dailyTotal + (dailyTotal*dailyPopulation*.01);
```